# Collabora “Unknown resource” because of Apache mod_rewrite proxy unescaping %2F slashes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-encoding, mod-proxy

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy with Apache 2.4.

It looks like I cannot use the horrible `mod_proxy` directly, as it does not support websockets (unless manually configured for every single URL), so I have to use the horrible horrible `mod_rewrite` instead.

My configuration looks as follows so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName collabora.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ wss://collabora-backend$1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/?
    RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ https://collabora-backend$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

One application that I’m trying to run (the horrible³ [Collabora Online in combination with NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/)) will try to open WebSockets to URLs like this: `ws://collabora.example.com/lool/https%253A%252F%252Fcloud.example.com%252Fapps%252Frichdocuments%252Fwopi%252Ffiles%252F51040%3Faccess_token%3DABCDEF%26permission%3Dedit/ws`. Unfortunately, with the configuration above, these URLs will arrive at the backend with all the `%25` parts decoded to `%` (and others as well): `ws://collabora.example.com/lool/https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.example.com%2Fapps%2Frichdocuments%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2F51040?access_token=ABCDEF&permission=edit/ws`.

Collabora will report error messages like this:

```
wsd-00026-0195 0:01:27.448231 [ client_ws_0003 ] ERR Unknown resource: /lool//ws/lool/https%253A%252F%252Fowncloud.mydomain.fr%252Findex.php%252Fapps%252Frichdocuments%252Fwopi%252Ffiles%252F5%3Faccess_token=R...c&permission=edit/ws| LOOLWSD.cpp:1154
```

and the WebSocket connections will fail with a `400 Bad Request` error in the browser.

Setting [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) to `On` or `NoDecode` doesn’t change this. (As far as I understand, this only affects the value of `PATH_INFO`.)

Reading through the [`RewriteRule` flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html), the `[B]` flag seems to talk about something related to my problem. There it says “mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them” (I assume the sole reason for that being to maximise annoyance), so the `[B]` flag will re-escape them again after the mapping. This of course doesn’t work in this case and will escape all the slashes, even the ones that were not escaped before: `"ws://collabora.example.com%2Flool%2Fhttps%253A%252F%252Fcloud.example.com%252Fapps%252Frichdocuments%252Fwopi%252Ffiles%252F51040%3Faccess_token%3DABCDEF%26permission%3Dedit%2Fws"`

Is there a way to fix this issue or is this the point where I finally have to get rid of Apache for good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on covener’s answer, I have now come up with the following configuration that works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName collabora.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[a-zA-Z]+ /(.*) HTTP/\d+(\.\d+)?$"
    RewriteRule .? wss://collabora-backend/%1 [P,NE]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/?
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[a-zA-Z]+ /(.*) HTTP/\d+(\.\d+)?$"
    RewriteRule .? https://collabora-backend/%1 [P,NE]
</VirtualHost>
```

I adjusted covener’s answer to support all kinds of HTTP requests, and I had to add the `NE` flag (otherwise the request URI would be escaped once more).

Answer (score 0):

One trick in this area is to use a capture of %{THE_REQUEST} instead of a backreference, because it will use the requests original encoding, such as:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName collabora.example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^GET /(.*) HTTP/1.?$"
    RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ wss://collabora-backend/%1 [P]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/acme-challenge/?
    RewriteRule ^(/.*)?$ https://collabora-backend$1 [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

I only added the new condition w/ capture and changed $1 to %1. I only desk-checked, but I suspect it gets you passed the encoding issue with only a few small tweaks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn’t aware that you can make back references to `RewriteCond`s. I managed to get it to work with some tweks, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Collabora updated the documentation and I ran in the same issue.

So there is a much nicer solution (found at https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/)

```
  AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
  ProxyPassMatch "/lool/(.*)/ws$" wss://127.0.0.1:9980/lool/$1/ws nocanon
```

Comment: Personally, I really don’t like having to specify for each URL pattern whether it will use websockets or not. In my case, my Apache config is even automatically generated, and I would have to add an unnecessary amount of logic to support this. As far as I know, `nocanon` is only supported with the `ProxyPass` directive and not `RewriteRule`, but `ProxyPass` does not have an equivalent to `RewriteCond` to filter whether the request is a websocket or not.